# Is there a way to move files from the Android Studio emulator to host device programmatically?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm implementing functionality for screenshot testing for my application where I take a screenshot within JUnit test by writing the bitmap of the root view to a file in the emulator file system. I'm looking to save that screenshot file to the host file system where my repository exists; however, the screenshot is saved on the emulator's file system. Furthermore, in the current set of settings that are enabled, the emulator restarts after each test is run, so it looses the screenshot after a test is run.

Using Kotlin code in my JUnit test cases, I was wondering if anybody would be knowledgeable on how to send files that are in the emulator to the host file system programmatically in the emulator run-time. I'm unsure if this is possible; however, any guidance on approaching this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I've tried sending files after the test cases are run; however, all screenshots except those that are made in the final test case are lost due to the emulator restarting after each test case runs, despite my expectation that they would persist.

Comment: Some emulator allow to directly access the file system of hist PC but Android Studio emulator does not. Therefore the only chance ai see is running a network service on the host PC and forward the server TCP port into the emulator. This would allow you to write the screen shot directly to that service and save it outside of the emulator instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out, using the `TestStorage` API from `androidx.test.services` allows for files to be maintained throughout the state of the application by saving them into a specific folder that does not reset after each test.